# Tiled image in QGraphicsView foreground

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qpixmap

I'm working on a Qt application made with a main QGraphicsView.

This view can show and switch between differents QgraphicsScenes. This application needs to always have an overlay in front of each scenes, so the best way to do this overlay is by `setForegroundBrush()` method of QGraphicsView.

But my overlay is a tiled-image, where I could edit the opacity and the scale of the source image.

Here's the code written in my QGraphicsView class constructor :

```
QString imgPath("path/to/image.png");
QPixmap map(imgPath);
QPainter painter(this);
QRectF zone(0,0,map.width(),map.height());
painter.drawPixmap(zone,map,zone);
QBrush brush = painter.brush();
brush.setStyle(Qt::TexturePattern);
setForegroundBrush(brush);
```

But doesn't work, nothing is shown.
I tested a simple QBrush with a QPixmap and works fine, but I need to use QPainter to be able to edit the opacity of my image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I think the easiest way to have a tiled image in QGraphicsView foreground is by reimplmenting the `drawForeground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)`.

```
void Frontend::drawForeground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect){
    float alpha = 0.15;
    float scale = 2;
    QString imgPath("path/to/image.png");
    QPixmap img(imgPath);
    painter->scale(scale,scale);
    painter->setOpacity(alpha);
    painter->drawTiledPixmap(rect,img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot paint on the widget outside of its `paintEvent` method. Perhaps you wanted to have the painter work on the pixmap (`painter(&map)`) instead of the widget (`painter(this)`)?

You could also add an overlay by:

1. Painting it in the reimplemented `paintEvent` of your derived scene, making sure that you paint not on the scene, but on its `viewport()`. There are convenience methods that are called by the view's `paintEvent`, such as `drawBackground` and `drawForeground`.
2. Painting it in a generic `QWidget` overlay.

I have [several answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1329652+%5Bqt%5D+overlay) that demonstrate how to get overlays over widgets in generaly, and also on scene views.

Comment: Thank you, but I just see I can reimplement drawForeground(QPainter * painter) method in my QGraphicsView class, and with this function I can see the overlay, but not tiled. Is it possible to get tiled overlay directly on this function ?

Comment: @mickaelb91 Yes, the various `drawXxx` convenience methods are a way to patch into the `paintEvent` without having to directly override it. If you can use them - do so.